# Nginx server response time is unexpectedly high for one in hundreds of requests

Tags: nginx, http, response-time

I'm using Nginx to serve .ts files for live streaming (HLS). Everything works fine but there is a problem with the response time of the files. Occasionally, some .ts files received from the server have an unexpectedly high response time which is problematic in our use case.

I have used a python script to find what's the problem.
[image: output of python script printing response time]

In this screenshot full response time is the time between the request is sent and the full response is received. The second parameter shown is the time between a request being sent and a response being received. (I've used response.elapsed.total_seconds() in the requests package of python). In slow requests, full response time is higher but response.elapsed.total_seconds() is OK. (And by higher I mean 3-4 times the average response time.)

On top of this problem, I have another problem in which both response time (response.elapsed.total_seconds()) and full response time is high. This case happens less frequently (maybe once in 200 requests) and response times are much higher than in the first case.

I should mention that I have some other machines in front of this machine to proxy and cache files. But doesn't matter if I request the cache machines or the main one. The result is the same.

Here's my Nginx config:

```
user  root;
worker_processes  16;

worker_rlimit_nofile 1000000;

master_process on;

pid        /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  500000;
    accept_mutex off;
    multi_accept off;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush on;

    server_tokens off;

    keepalive_timeout  150;
#    keepalive_requests 5;

    aio on;
    gzip on;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 4k;
    client_body_buffer_size 1k;
    client_max_body_size 1k;
    client_body_timeout 12;
    client_header_timeout 12;
    send_timeout 10;
    tcp_nodelay       on;
    sendfile_max_chunk 1m;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    vhost_traffic_status_zone shared:vhost_traffic_status:10m;
    underscores_in_headers on;
    recursive_error_pages on;

    server {
        listen 80 backlog=10000000;
        location /tmp {
            access_log /cache/nginx.log main;
            types {
                application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
                video/mp2t ts;
            }
            alias /cache/hls;
            add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
     }
}
```

Nginx access and error logs don't show anything abnormal. Neither for the good responses nor the slow ones.

I couldn't find anything about this problem until now. Hope I could find an answer here.